# JS Regex: Match word in a string between single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex which yields any string between single quotes ('), IF that string contains a given word.

For example, assume I have the following text, and I want to match everything between single quotes that contains the word "test":

```
Some sample text,
'this is test a match' and
'this is not a match' but
'this is a match again because it contains the word test'.
This "is not a test match because its double quotes".
And this is not a test match either because this is not encapsulated in quotes.
```

The regex would need to return two matches, namely

```
"this is a test match"
"this is a match again because it contains the word test"
```

I'm a bit lost here. I tried text.match( /'(.*?)'/); to return everything between single quotes, and then subsequently have a function check for a substring match. But oddly that regex didn't even seem to return all strings within single quotes property.

Would greatly appreciate a pointer.. thanks!

Comment: please format your inline code correctly like so: `\`code\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fooled around with your example on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com) and figured out following expression: `'(.*)test(.*)'`

Comment: This does not work for strings with multiple quote phrases: try '(.*?)test(.*?)'

Answer (score 10):

Your regex is correct except you want to match all occurance so use `g` for global search for all matches:

```
 text.match(/'(.*?)'/g)
```

and to match for exact word:

```
 text.match(/'(.*?test.*?)'/g)
```

You can allow it to be generic for any word by formulate the Regualr Expression using:

```
word = 'test'
text.match(RegExp("'(.*?"+word+".*?)'", 'g'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works

`/\'.*(test).*\'/g`

https://regex101.com/r/bD6zF0/1